# Is there an uglifying/minifying library which allows to exclude indicated character sets?

Tags: javascript, minify, ejs, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I have to exclude non-javascript character sets like `<%`,`<%-`, `<%=` and `%>` character sets when I uglifying / minifying javascript codes. (Just these characters)

For example the below codes should be transform to its below codes after uglified/minified process;

**raw codes;**

```
 <% if (!user.admin) { %>
    var a=1;
    console.log(a);
 <% } %>
```

**minified codes;**

```
 <% if (!user.admin) { %>var a=1;console.log(a);<% } %>
```

Comment: Just an idea - instead of finding a minifying library that supports this, why not break the problem into parts? First run a program that strips those characters (something like `awk` maybe), then you can minify normally.

Comment: Hi @MaximillianLaumeister, Thanks. I'd never heard `awk` before. I looked at that. However my development environment on Windows. I guess I should write a simple tool to remove white spaces except `<%- %>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin

Take a look at specifically https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#blockreplacements

Define your own block and replace it with whatever suits you.

Comment: Hi @elad.chen , thanks for your advice. However I want to leave the same my block instead of replace.